# What is the equivalent of Struts ActionMessages in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, struts

Please let me know if you have any idea about it.

Thanks

**EDIT**

What ActionMessages is?

`ActionMessages` is basically a class that holds messages that you want to display on a JSP page. Messages can be added in `ActionMessages` in an `Action`(controller) class. On the JSP, the position where the messages are intended to be displayed, is marked by `<html:messages/>` tag. Hence, all your messages are rendered automatically on that specific position.

These messages are usually feedback texts that need to appear after some user actions. For example, if the user creates a new record, a feedback message could be "Record created successfully!".

Comment: Explain what an ActionMessage is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring has an `Errors` class (refer to the [Chapter 5. Validation, Data-binding, the BeanWrapper, and PropertyEditors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html)) to report... errors but no direct equivalent of Struts `ActionMessage` (can be used for regular messages too, not only errors). There is a Jira issue about this: [SPR-2657](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-2657).